# Is it right to call implemented method in DI?

Tags: .net, dependency-injection, .net-core

I did an implement dependency injection in .net core and call mentioned from the interface as mentioned below code.

Controller

```
    private readonly ILogger<HomeController> _logger;
    private readonly IManageUsers  _IManageUsers;

    public HomeController(ILogger<HomeController> logger, IManageUsers manageUsers)
    {
        _logger = logger;
        _IManageUsers = manageUsers;
    }

    public IActionResult Index()
    {
       string data =  _IManageUsers.GetData();
        return View();
    }
```

interface declaration code

```
    public interface IManageUsers
    {
        string GetData();
    }
```

implementation method code

```
    public string GetData()
    {
        return "DI implemented successfully";
    }
```

When I'm debugging code from the controller that time called declaration mentioned not an interface method. what I'm doing wrong?

Answer (score 2):

You're doing everything correctly.

When your `HomeController` is invoked, an instance of an object that implements `IManageUsers` is passed into the constructor.  When you call `GetData` on that instance, the method from the implementation is invoked.

Interfaces simply define what methods and properties must exist on the implementation.  They have no implementation of their own (... well, except for [default interface methods](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-8.0/default-interface-methods), but that's an entirely different subject and is not the case for your `GetData` method).

Comment: It's great if you provide me one example code for that because I lots of tried but did not call the interface method

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you're asking.  As I said, you're doing everything correctly.  When you call a method on the interface, it invokes the method on your implementation.  That is how interfaces work, by design of interfaces.